# Hide/Show works fine but slide is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a news ticker which basically hides a headline and shows the next one. Everything is working find but as soon as I use the hide('slide') method, it stops working. It hides the first element by sliding it but never shows the next element.

Note- I have added all the required JS files so that's not a problem.

```
//Slide Headlines **(Working Code Without Sliding)**
setInterval(function(){
    $('.headlines_container a').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
            $(this).hide();
            if($(this).next().is('a')){
                $(this).next('a').show();
                return false;
            }else{  
                $(this).closest('.headlines_container').find('a').first().show();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
},2000);


//Slide Headlines **(Not Working)**
setInterval(function(){
    $('.headlines_container a').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
            $(this).hide('slide',{direction:'left'});
            if($(this).next().is('a')){
                $(this).next('a').show('slide',{direction:'right'});
                return false;
            }else{  
                $(this).closest('.headlines_container').find('a').first().show('slide',{direction:'right'});
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
},2000);
```

Comment: please share your html for relevant elements

Comment: Fixed it. All I had to do was to add position:absolute property to the element.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).hide('slide',{direction:'left'});`  requires the `jQuery-ui library`. Are you using that library? You may pass a timespan too while calling `hide` function.

```
$(this).hide('slide',{direction:'left'}, 1000);
```

Have a look here

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/